# Django Queryset find data between date

Tags: python, django

I don't know what title should be, I just got stuck and need to ask.

I have a model called `shift`

and imagine the db_table like this:

```
#table shift
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+------------+------------+
| start         | end           | off_start     | off_end       | time       | user_id    |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+------------+------------+
| 2018-01-01    | 2018-01-05    | 2018-01-06    | 2018-01-07    | 07:00      | 1          |
| 2018-01-08    | 2018-01-14    | 2018-01-15    | Null          | 12:00      | 1          |
| 2018-01-16    | 2018-01-20    | 2018-01-21    | 2018-01-22    | 18:00      | 1          |
| 2018-01-23    | 2018-01-27    | 2018-01-28    | 2018-01-31    | 24:00      | 1          |
| ....          | ....          | ....          | ....          | ....       | ....       |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+------------+------------+
```

if I use queryset with filter like `start=2018-01-01` result will `07:00`

but how to get result `12:00` if I Input `2018-01-10` ?...

thank you!

Comment: Can you share your `shift` model? Can `start` and/or `end` be `NULL`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem only `off_end` can be `NULL`

Comment: but that is not relevant here, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question isnt too clear, but maybe you're after something like 
`start__lte=2018-01-10, end__gte=2018-01-10`?

Answer (score 0):

Well usually you can do that with an interval check: the `start` should be less than or equal to the date you want to query, and the `end` should be greater than or equal than the date you want to query.

So you can obtain the `Shift` instances where they have a time range that includes the given range with:

```
from datetime import date

t0 = date(2018, 1, 10)

Shift.objects.filter(start__lte=t0, end__gte=t0)
```

In case the `start` and/or `end` dates are *non* inclusive, remove the corresponding `e` suffix(es).